# Movieclips Overlapping

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been learning as3 for about 2 weeks

I'm trying to make a combo generator for personal uses

The problem is that if the same MovieClip inside the array is displayed twice or more it just overlapps it.

for example when the elbow is displayed a second time ,it just overlaps the 1st elbow movieclip! http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/208/17797019.png

Here's my code

```
var punch:Punch = new Punch();
var kick:Kick = new Kick();
var knee:Knee = new Knee();
var elbow:Elbow = new Elbow();
var holder:MovieClip; // for displaying purposes 
var position:Number = 100;

public function Main()
{
    var combo:Array = [punch, kick, knee, elbow];
    for(var i:Number = 0;i < 2;i++ )
    {
        holder = combo[randomNumber()]
        holder.y = 200;
        holder.x = position;        
        addChild(holder);
        position = position + 100;
    }


}
function randomNumber():Number
{
    return(Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 )+1));
}
```

Comment: can you explain more please , or attach some printscreen

Comment: Well, should it be displayed twice? If so, should both overlap? Things overlap if you put them in same place, not much else they can do.

Comment: why you duplicating this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007844/overlapping-movieclips

Comment: sorry,I won't do it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code like this:

```
public function Main()
{
    var combo:Array = [Punch, Kick, Knee, Elbow];
    for(var i:Number = 0;i < 2;i++ )
    {
        var motion:MovieClip = new combo[randomNumber()]();           
        motion.y = 200;
        motion.x = i*100;        
        addChild(motion);
    }    
}
function randomNumber():Number
{
    return(Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 )+1));
}
```

Comment: I intentionally want it to repeat the movielcips if possile

Comment: @AlexisKyleSales it is not possible ,  you need to have copies of these movieclips

Comment: @AlexisKyleSales what exactly you want to see on the stage?

Comment: each MovieClips that has different x values

Answer (score 0):

I think your real issue is that you have objects in that array multiple times in the first place. I guess you want to add 2 elbows; a left and a right. That means you need 2 elbow objects (the way objects work is that you have a single class, many instances. The same instance cannot be in multiple places, because it has only one set of properties)

So you need to make (say) `var elbowL:Elbow = new Elbow(); var elbowR:Elbow = new Elbow();` and add both to the array.

As for the overlapping, I believe an object can only be added to the stage *once*, so adding it a second time *replaces* the first. In this case that's making no difference though (except changing the z-order); the elbow is being moved as soon as you change it's `x` or `y` property. With the change I suggested above, that's no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you wish for two "Elbow"s to appear at once? Well you only have one instance of the Elbow class, so that wont work.

I recommend that you have a function which takes in an integer, and returns the new instance of the appropriate MovieClip:

```
function NewMove(id:int):MovieClip
{
    switch(id)
    {
        case 1: return new Punch();
        case 2: return new Kick();
        case 3: return new Knee();
        case 4: return new Elbow();
    }
    return new MovieClip();
}
```

So your code would be:

```
for(var i:Number = 0;i < 2;i++ )
{
    holder = NewMove(randomNumber());
    holder.y = 200;
    holder.x = position;        
    addChild(holder);
    position = position + 100;
}
```